# jsf edit rows, database performance

Tags: jsf, datatable

i am new to JSF and i followed an online sample to take the edit data table as follows. May i know is this the good practice because i doubt that when the user the save the table, it will update every rows in the database thus it will causes the slow performance issue right?by the way, is JSF come with auto ajax? or it have to depend on jsf library like richfaces, primefaces and etc.

[image: http://s15.postimg.org/8ohxzzesb/Capture.png]

[image: http://s28.postimg.org/691hn67wt/Captureq.png]

Answer (score 0):

> when the user the save the table, it will update every rows in the database

Instead of saving all the elements of the list, it's better to create another list with the elements that have been edited and then save the filtered list. This way you are only updating the edited elements, not all elements.

> is JSF come with auto ajax?

You can add AJAX functionality to standard JSF components with the `<f:ajax>` tag. See http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/core/f_ajax.html.

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark the question as correct!